# Download CSV file without link in R

Tags: r, csv

I want to download the csv file, mentioned besides "Download All Records" on this [webpage](https://www.bseindia.com/markets/equity/EQReports/StockPrcHistori.aspx?expandable=7&scripcode=530077&flag=sp&Submit=G) in R.

```
url <- "https://www.bseindia.com/markets/equity/EQReports/StockPrcHistori.aspx?expandable=7&scripcode=530077&flag=sp&Submit=G"
temporaryFilePath <- tempfile()
download.file(url, destfile = temporaryFilePath, method="auto")
url.data <- read.csv(temporaryFilePath)
url.data
```

I have tried a few different methods using `rvest`, `RCurl` and `XML` but not luck so far.

Comment: I'm confused. The URL doesn't link to a CSV file. Is this about scraping the data?

Comment: When you go to the url, there is an Excel icon (near top right). If we click on it, a csv file is downloaded. I need to download this file. I know there is no direct link to the csv and hence the problem.

Comment: The way to go here is to use RSelenium.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to get finance data, try follow the steps below.

```
#Install Packages
library(quantmod)
library(plyr)


##set the default source to your function
setDefaults(getSymbols, src='google')


##Choosing the argu,ents

##You must find the symbol in yahoo finance website
symbol <- "AAPL"


##Start Date
StartDate = as.Date("2018-01-31") 

##End Date
EndDate = as.Date("2018-03-15")

##Getting your stock price
StockData <- getSymbols(symbol, from=StartDate, to=EndDate, auto.assign=F)


##After obtain the data, you can make some adjusts
colnames(StockData) <- c("Open", "High", "Low", "Close","Volume")
```

Comment: I'm not sure but isn't this feature in Google Finance depreciated. I don't want to lose dependencies in future and hence want to direct parse from the webpage.